# What is {built-in method load} when I run cProfile in Python?

Tags: python, django, profiling, cprofile

I'm running cProfile to benchmark my Django application. The relevant lines look like this:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    3    0.027    0.009    0.027    0.009 {built-in method load}
  149    0.004    0.000    0.007    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:275(__init__)
  149    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/compiler.py:4(resolve_columns)
  349/72    0.002    0.000    0.007    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py:145(deepcopy)
```

What is {built-in method load}? It is dominating my execution.

Comment: It's some builtin function called `load`.  Use the profiler's ability to print callers to see what is calling it, that should help you figure out what it is.  One possibility that comes to mind is [`pickle.load`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.load).

Comment: It may be dominating execution, but at 27ms it still looks incredibly pointless to try to optimize it...